# Django Debug Toolbar Panels Don't Show Data

Tags: django-debug-toolbar

I have configured the django-debug-toolbar like so:

```
DEBUG = True
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...,
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    ...,
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'debug_toolbar',
    ...,
)
```

And the toolbar shows up for me:[image: panel], but when I click on one of the toolbars like SQL I get no detailed information:
[image]

No errors in the console. Wondering why I don't get detailed info when clicking the panel.

I'm using Django 1.7 and installed django-debug-toolbar 1.3

Answer (score 2):

Moving the **debug** url to the first url pattern solved this